# Jszip and jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jszip

I want to realize zipping .exe files from server, while somebody downloads files using checkboxes, but not the point. Trying to understand how jszip works.
But I have some issues : downloader example doesn't work correctly. 
I take an example from https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/downloader.html , delete some excess features like styles, links etc.
Almost all runs correct except block: 
 **JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {..}**
- this section doesn't execute, it gives me an **error** : 
 " Error: InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is" or 'text'(was'arraybuffer'). " 
Also I have another question: if I place script "demo.js" in header section script doesn't run by pressing button. Scripts should be downloaded because they are small size and header loading faster then body. I read that best way to include scripts is to place they right in the end of body, before closing tag. But if I place all my scripts in the end of body nothing happens when button is pressed. Why it works that way? I red many articles but don't find an answer. I'm new in JS so don't beat me hard). 
I'll be very appreciate for any help and suggestions.

this is my 1.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>something</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jszip.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jszip-utils.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/FileSaver.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form action="#" id="download_form">
<ul>
    <li>
      <label>
       <input type="checkbox" data-url="dist/jszip.js" checked />
    dist/jszip.js
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-url="dist/demo.js" checked />
    dist/demo.js
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-url="dist/FileSaver.js" />
    dist/FileSaver.js
  </label>
   </li>
  </ul>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">pack them !</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/demo.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

and here is demo.js:

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
  "use strict";

/**
 * Reset the message.
 */
function resetMessage () {
    $("#result")
    .removeClass()
    .text("");
}
/**
 * show a successful message.
 * @param {String} text the text to show.
 */
function showMessage(text) {
    resetMessage();
    $("#result")
    .addClass("alert alert-success")
    .text(text);
}
/**
 * show an error message.
 * @param {String} text the text to show.
 */
function showError(text) {
    resetMessage();
    $("#result")
    .addClass("alert alert-danger")
    .text(text);
}

/**
 * Fetch the content, add it to the JSZip object
 * and use a jQuery deferred to hold the result.
 * @param {String} url the url of the content to fetch.
 * @param {String} filename the filename to use in the JSZip object.
 * @param {JSZip} zip the JSZip instance.
 * @return {jQuery.Deferred} the deferred containing the data.
 */
function deferredAddZip(url, filename, zip) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return deferred;
}

if(!JSZip.support.blob) {
    showError("This demo works only with a recent browser !");
    return;
}

 var $form = $("#download_form").on("submit", function () {
 alert("button press");   /* it works fine */
    resetMessage();

    var zip = new JSZip();
    var deferreds = [];

    // find every checked item
    $(this).find(":checked").each(function () { 
        var $this = $(this);
        var url = $this.data("url");
        var filename = url.replace(/.*\//g, "");
        deferreds.push(deferredAddZip(url, filename, zip));
    });

    // when everything has been downloaded, we can trigger the dl


    // section below doesn't work at all - alerts used for simplest debugging
    $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
        //alert("downloading must start");
        var blob = zip.generate({type:"blob"});

        // see FileSaver.js
        saveAs(blob, "example.zip");

        showMessage("done !");
    }).fail(function (err) {
        showError(err);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

my file folder which includes files looks like:

- -root folder:

  - 1.html

    - subfolder "dist":

      - demo.js
      - FileSaver.js
      - jquery-1.8.3.min.js
      - jszip.js
      - jszip-utils.js

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description

Comment: I corrected and update problem description)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved my problem.
The problem is that html file was opened in browser on my local machine using                  **file:///**  protocol. For correct work it should use **http** protocol. 
So I download apache server, run on my pc and start my html file on apache server which worked correctly.